# Avoid 'out of shared memory error' in PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, out-of-memory, sql-function

I have two tables, a table called *companies_display* with information about publicly traded companies such as ticker symbol, market cap etc. and a partitioned table *stock_prices* with the historical stock prices for each company.
I want to calculate the beta of each stock and write that into *companies_display*.
For that I wrote the function *calculate_beta(ticker)* that calculates it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_beta (VARCHAR)
RETURNS float8 AS $beta$
DECLARE
    beta float8;
BEGIN
    WITH weekly_returns AS (
        WITH RECURSIVE
        spy AS (
            SELECT time, close FROM stock_prices WHERE ticker = 'SPY'
        ),
        stock AS (
            SELECT time, close FROM stock_prices WHERE ticker = $1
        )
        SELECT
            spy.time,
            stock.close / LAG(stock.close) OVER (ORDER BY spy.time DESC) AS stock,
            spy.close / LAG(spy.close) OVER (ORDER BY spy.time DESC) AS spy
        FROM stock
        JOIN spy
        ON stock.time = spy.time
        WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM spy.time) = 1
        ORDER BY spy.time DESC
        LIMIT 52
    )
    SELECT 
        COVAR_SAMP(stock, spy) / VAR_SAMP(spy) INTO beta
    FROM weekly_returns
    ;
    RETURN beta;
END;
$beta$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function works for just a few companies, but when i tried to update the whole table

```
UPDATE companies_display SET beta = calculate_beta(ticker);
```

I get an out of shared memory error and it says that max_locks_per_transaction is too low.
My guess is that the function creates a lock on the *stock_prices* table for each company and doesn't drop them till it would have run to completion.
What I tried was to create a loop

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    ticker_ VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    FOR ticker_ IN SELECT ticker FROM companies_display
    LOOP
        UPDATE companies_display
        SET beta = calculate_beta(ticker_)
        WHERE ticker = ticker_
        ;
    END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

but I ran into the same problem.
Is there a way to drop the lock on *stock_prices* after each beta calculation or do the update in batches?
For about 5 companies at a time my method works.

Comment: Please show us the full error message.  How many partitions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into the same problem, I avoided the error by calling my sql function from the server I use to update my database. That way I have one transaction per company and I don't get to many locks.